# Increase 3 seconds to the timer when the button has been clicked Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, timer, cocos2d-iphone

Sorry this is probably a dumb question but I have been struggling with this for a while. I’m kind of new to Cocos2d, but I have a schedule timer set to 3 secs to make a sprite disappear and every time they click the button it adds 3 seconds to the timer, the problem i'm having is when they click the button it wont add 3 seconds to the timer, the timer just ends,

Comment: post the code that u used for timer

Comment: you can end the previous timer and start a new timer of same name  with 3 seconds added to it.

Comment: Post something so that we can figure out what's wrong with your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[_timer setFireDate:[[_timer fireDate] dateByAddingTimeInterval:600]];
```

This would add 10 minutes (600 seconds) to my _timer.

Answer (score 3):

In cocos2d, its better  to use scheduler instead of NSTimer and you can change fire interval time with following api.

```
[self schedule: @selector(tick:) interval:0.03f];

[self unschedule:@selector(tick:)];

[self schedule: @selector(tick:) interval:0.05f];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
[self performSelector:@selector(tick:)withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```